# Fastparse parse error column numbers missing

Tags: scala, fastparse

I just updated from fastparse 0.3.7 to 0.4.1.  There is no longer a column number value in the extras of a Parsed.Failure.  I grepped through the source and it seems the functionality has been removed, though it is still in the documentation.  Is there some other way to get column info now?

Comment: Just look through a previous tag for the implementation and use an `implicit class` to re-add it.

Comment: Surely a parser library has a way to get the error location.

Answer (score 1):

It's just changed a bit.  You need to grab the index and the parser that failed, and call `StringReprOps.prettyIndex`.